# How to write a custom pretty printer

Tags: algorithm, pretty-print

A problem that has frequently come up in my career is I have some kind of data structure (perhaps an s-expression) and I want to print it in a human readable form complete with reasonable indentation choices.

Is there a book or blog entry that describes how to do this elegantly?  I am interested in the algorithm more than a specific library.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

S-Exps are equivalent to tree structures, if you can pretty-print a tree you can pretty-print an s-exp.

For instance, compare:

```
(tree
    (value 89)
    (tree
        (value 9)
        nil
        nil)
    (tree
        (value 456)
        nil
        nil))
```

to:

```
89
 +- 9
 +- 456
```

The algorithm is identical, the only difference is the ammount of surrounding data you want to print out.

[This paper](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/prettier/prettier.pdf) describes an algorithm for pretty-printing trees

[This one](ftp://reports.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/79/770/CS-TR-79-770.pdf) describes a pretty-printer for programming languages

Comment: The second link is no longer available.

Comment: The second link is to Derek C. Oppen's 1979 publication "PRETTY PRINTING." It's report number is: CS-TR-79-770. It can currently be found at http://i.stanford.edu/TR/CS-TR-79-770.html with a direct link at http://i.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/79/770/CS-TR-79-770.pdf